# ASP .NET WebSite with importing DLL-s

Tags: asp.net, dll

I am trying to call a DLL function in my file.aspx.cs like this:

```
[DllImport("the.dll")]
private static extern bool theFunction(int width, int height);
```

And:

- file "the.dll" is in "C:\Windows\System32\inetsvr"
- my web site is an application that has the privileges to read and execute it
- if I try `File.Exists("the.dll")` on the server it returns true, so the DLL is on the server "path"

But:

- if I try to run the page on localhost, all is OK
- if I try to run the page uploaded on IIS server, the page loads to infinity... Nothing shows up, nothing happens!? And then IIS gets blocked and I have to restart the server.

What am I doing wrong? o_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check security and permissions settings on IIS.
Also try putting dll in bin folder.